# Check if each email in inbox is replied to or not - asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I want to check if each of the emails in my inbox is replied to or not. If yes, then what is the replied date.

For eg: loop through each email in my inbox and check a property, say,

```
if (oMailItem.IsReplied==true ){        
    strSentOnDate=oMailItem.SentOn 
} //replied to date
```

How to do this in asp.net c#
. Am using MS Outlook

Comment: What code you have written for this? What issue you are facing with this?

Comment: MS Outlook API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations

Comment: Are you attempting to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop` in an ASP.NET application? If so you should be aware that [it is not officially supported by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office), and generally is also very prone to errors. Maybe consider using Exchange Web Services in your ASP.NET application instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use EWS Conversations:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn610351(v=exchg.150).aspx

Then cycle through the items in the conversation looking for the InReplyTo field equal to your original message ID.